# Injecting different bean according to resource method called

Tags: java, dependency-injection, cdi

We're using `CDI` in our application (NOT `EJB`). We have a resources layer, a business beans layer and a database handler beans layer. All those beans are `@RequestScoped`. Right now the resource injects a business bean which in turn injects all dbhandler beans it requires. Since this is `CDI` and there is no object pooling (at least from what I know) is there a way to decide which beans get injected (and thus created) depending on the method called? For example, I have 2 business bean methods. Method1 uses `DAOBean1` and Method2 uses `DAOBean1` AND `DAOBean2`. Right now, even if I only want to use Method1, the business bean will inject both DAO beans. Is there a way to filter injected beans according to the method call? This is important because we have a bean that creates a datasource connection on its `@PostConstruct` but not all bean methods query the database which means that we create redundant connections when using the bean for non db related methods.

Comment: Sounds like a preferable option is to inject a connection pool.

Comment: Well an easy fix would be to not inject DAOBean2, but rather look it up programmatically through the CDI BeanManager. Then you get on-demand creation of the bean.

Comment: Those are good workarounds but I'm looking for a solution to the described problem. The connection issue is just one problem that arises from unfiltered bean injection.

Comment: What scope are these beans?

Comment: `@RequestScope`. With the other scopes (Application, Session) there wouldn't be a problem since they perpetually exist in an active session. The only solution I've found is using some kind of ProgrammaticLookup (either through `Instance<MyBean>` injection or using the `BeanManager`) and it works fine but right now I'm curious for a more elegant solution. Ultimately I'd like to describe what beans each function needs and have them injected dynamically after the function call but before function execution. Using `Interceptor` sounds like a solution but I don't think it can be implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is no way to have different beans injected according to the method called. Since injections are resolves during the bean creation, the container cannot know which function is going to be called and can't hold on to the injection until we decide. To solve this we either use Programmatic Bean Lookup (using the `BeanManager` class) to access in-context beans or we can access them through the `Instance<T>` interface. If we use the `Instance` interface, we must be careful to not have memory leaks. Why is that? Because every bean injected that way gains the scope `@Dependent` which means it will be released when the injector class itself is destroyed. If the injector class's scope is for example `@ApplicationScoped` the bean itself will never be released thus creating a memory leak. In cases like those we use the `Instance` interface's method called `destroy(myBean).

Example:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyClass {

  @Inject
  Instance<MyBean> myBeanInstance;

  public void myMethod() {
    //...
    MyBean bean = myBeanInstance.get();
    // Do stuff with bean
    myBeanInstance.destroy(bean); //Release the bean otherwise it will hold memory
  }
}
```